# Sending Multiple Objects from Angular 8 to .Net Core Web Api - Null at Controller End

Tags: c#, typescript, angular8, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following method which sends multiple objects to .Net Core Web API

```
 this.http.post('api/InternalReport/create', [
              this.internalreport,
              this.file]
            , { observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(data => {
                if (data.status == 200) { console.log("success");}
              }, err => { console.error('Observer got an error:');});
```

The API Controller

```
[HttpPost("create")]
        public ActionResult<InternalReport> Create([FromBody]InternalReport report,[FromBody]File file)
        {
            try
            {
                _internalreportService.Create(report);
                _fileservice.Update(file.sha1,file);
                return Ok("success");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }



        }
```

But both the objects are null at the controller side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JsonType,you can only pass an object,If you want to pass multiple objects,you need to create a new object contain the multiple objects.
Here is a demo worked:

AngularData:

```
public class AngularData
    {
        public Student student { get; set; }
        public string a { get; set; }

    }
```

Student:

```
public class Student
    {
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

SendData:

```
SendData() {
  var student={'Gender':'male'};
  var angulardata={student,'a':'aaa'}
   const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');
   this.http.post('https://localhost:44363/create',JSON.stringify(angulardata),{headers:headers})
.subscribe(data => {
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost("create")]
        public IActionResult  Create([FromBody]AngularData angularData)
        {
            return Ok();



        }
```

result:
[image]